# How to check if 2 Bitmaps are equal in Robolectric 3.1.2

Tags: android, unit-testing, bitmap, robolectric

Just like the question implies, I'm looking for a way to check to see if 2 Bitmaps created from image URLs are equal.

I tried assertEquals, despite the fact that the 2 image urls are the same, but when converted to Bitmap, they aren't the same despite the fact that they went through the same check to get put into a Bitmap.

I'm using Robolectric 3.1.2, with the latest version of Gradle and Android Studio.

Any Input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would say to make sure bitmaps are equal you have to check equality of every bit. Which I don't see much value as well is a quite expensive operation. In addition **Robolectric** pretends to be Android but it is not supporting full bitmaps support. Can you explain test that you're trying to test?

Comment: Could you add some code excerpts how you're creating and comparing them?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just use an MD5 algorithm, compute it for bitmap1 and bitmap2 and compare the values?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `sameAs` method from bitmap to compare two bitmaps.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29

Comment: That won't work in Robolectric. At least it didn't for me.